# What would be the simplest way to create a vertical or horizontal cell fracture / realistic wood break?

Tags: physics, collision, photorealism

I want to create a piece of cracking wood in blender for a project of mine, I made a blender-guru esque ball n' chain destruction setup, made a simple cell fracture wall, put a wood material on it, and that was it, but its pretty bad

This is **NOT** how wood should break.

[image]

What im trying to do is create that wood "sharding" effect. Is there a good method to do this in blender 2.8? I found a tutorial for an older version using cell fracture, and thats better, but its not what im going for, it still looks like a piece of metal or concrete: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_m81zF9WtY

Comment: Try some more extreme scale settings in the cell fracture addon, such as `1.0, 1.0, 0.1`. [Here's an example](https://imgur.com/AC6i04m) of how that looks.

Comment: @gandalf3 Thankyou, ill check some things out